# Count occurrences of an element in list

Tags: python, list, counter

I know that there are already a lot of questions about this specific topic, but I can't find a proper solution for my problem.

I have the input:

```
2, 20, 15, 16, 17, 3, 8, 10, 7
```

I want to see if there are 'double' numbers in my code. I have tried working with this code.

```
lijst = input('Give a list:  ')
teller = 0
for i in lijst.split(','):
    if lijst.count(i) != 1:
        teller += 1
print(teller != 0)
```

Normally I should get False, since there are no double numbers in the given list. However, I recieve True. I suggest that's because the 2 appears also in 20.

```
True
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this problem, so the the '2' isn't counted twice?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter` which does exactly that

```
>>> data = [2, 20, 15, 16, 17, 3, 8, 10, 7]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(data)
Counter({2: 1, 3: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 10: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1, 20: 1})
>>>
```

It counts number of occurences and returns a dict with keys indicates the item, and value is number of occurences.

If you just need to know if there are **duplicates** or not, regardless of which item is the duplicate, you can simply use `Set` over your list and check `len()` afterwards:

`len(data) == len(set(data))`

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the length of the input with the length of the set of unique elements in input:

```
def has_repeated_elements(input):
    """returns True if input has repeated elements,
    False otherwise"""
    return len(set(input)) != len(input)

print(not has_repeated_elements(input))
```